# Novice coder seeking guidance

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, error-handling

I need help for on this program for a problem that I can't seem to be able to solve

```
numblist = []

def two23(numblist):

    **if two23([0][1]) == 2:**
        return 'True'

    elif two23([0][1]) == 3:
        return 'True'

    else:
        return 'False'

print(two23([2, 3]))
```

This program is supposed to output true if the contents of the list are 2 and 2 or 3 and 3. if the list is 2 and 3, then the program will output false. 
whenever I try to run this code, I receive an error saying that the starred text is "out of range". Please help and Thank you in advance

Comment: `two23([0][1])` ???????????????????

Answer (score 0):

`[0][1]` refers to the element at index 1 of the list [0], but this list has only one element, at index 0, so you get the error message, "IndexError: list index out of range."  You surely don't mean

```
two23([0][1])
```

or even `two23([0])` as this would be a function call.  You just need

```
def two23(numblist):
   return numblist == [2,2] or numblist == [3,3]
```

No need for `if` statements.  You can even make it simpler:

```
def two23(numblist):
   return numblist in ([2,2],[3,3])
```

Comment: Sorry, ive edited the post to include the purpose of the program. its purpose is to output either true of false based on the contents of the list. true if the list contains 2 and 2 or 3 and 3. False if it contains anything else. Again, i am i very novice coder and this is my first post here.